# find the limit for f(x) when x approaches infinity

Tags: limits

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \lambda \frac{e^{-x/a}}{x},
$$
where $a, \lambda > 0$.

I think the limit is 0, but i am not sure. need your help

Comment: What is the function here?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  Please put your question in the post, not a link to the question.  Try to edit your question using this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: can you write in $\LaTeX$ please?

Comment: the searched limit is $0$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \lambda \frac{e^{-x/a}}{x}
 = \lambda \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{1}{xe^{x/a}}
 = 0,
$$
since $x$ and $e^{x/a}$ both become very large.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-x/a}=0$ & $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$

as the limits exist individually, hence separating the limits as follows, $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\lambda\frac{e^{-x/a}}{x}$$

$$=\lambda\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{e^{-x/a}}{x}$$
$$=\lambda\left(\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-x/a}\right)\cdot \left(\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
$$=\lambda (0)\cdot (0)=\color{red}{0}$$